# I am missing all oms related extensions in hybris 5.7 while migrating from 5.5 to 5.7.Is there any OMS related extensions available in hybris 5.7?

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am migrating from hybris 5.5 to 5.7 and so many extensions like "b2ccheckoutaddon" ,"omsclient","omsats","omsorders","omsbackoffice","dataonboardingclient" are missing . So is there any oms related extensions in hybris 5.7.I have installed only commerce-suite-5.7.zip .Is it mandatory to install commerce-suite-5.7-repository.zip for getting all those oms extensions ?
[image]

Comment: Hello, there is a guide to migrate from 5.6 to 5.7 it might help you : https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/OMS+Migration+from+5.6+to+5.7

Comment: Actually I am not migrating OMS . I am working on commerce.

Comment: If you're not using OMS, then just remove the extension from your localextensions and you won't have issue when starting the server.

Comment: I am not using OMS .But from commerce  I need to connect to oms through these extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `b2c_acc_oms` recipe to install OMS related extensions.

Check [Installing Order Management](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/docsap/Installing+Order+Management).

If not interested to install recipe, just check its `build.gradle` file, you will find extensions list. Also you can refer [Migration Guide](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/OMS+Migration+from+5.6+to+5.7).

Extensions -

- warehousing
- warehousingbackoffice
- ordermanagementbackoffice
- yacceleratorordermanagement

Answer (score 0):

Since Hybris 5.7 OMS is built on top of the core platform (in prior versions OMS was a core+ microservice -> CIS) this means now you only need the 4 following extensions :

- ordermanagementbackoffice
- warehousingbackoffice
- yacceleratorordermanagement
- warehousing

Source : [Hybris wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=285414422)

Comment: What to do with these extensions like "b2ccheckoutaddon" ,"omsclient","omsats","omsorders","omsbackoffice","dataonboardingclient" as at time of build these are missing.

Comment: Actually it is showing "SolrQueryConverter" as deprecated in Hybris 5.7.I need some more info regarding this.